# Has anyone implemented robolectric 2.3 with couchbase-lite-android 1.02?

Tags: java, android, couchbase, robolectric

I have a project that I've implemented couchbase-lite-android and it works very well, however.. I've been trying to add in Robolectric to work on adding unit and component tests but have not had any luck getting these two to work together. Currently I'm receiving the following issue.

DEBUG: Loading resources for android from jar:C:\Users\brad.m2\repository\org\robolectric\android-all\4.3_r2-robolectric-0\android-all-4.3_r2-robolectric-0.jar!/res...

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no com_couchbase_touchdb_TDCollateJSON in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at com.couchbase.touchdb.TDCollateJSON.(TDCollateJSON.java:36)
at com.couchbase.lite.android.AndroidSQLiteStorageEngine.open(AndroidSQLiteStorageEngine.java:46)
at com.couchbase.lite.Database.open(Database.java:911)
at com.couchbase.lite.Manager.getDatabase(Manager.java:227)
at com.snapterm.core.models.transaction.TransactionsDb.initDatabase(TransactionsDb.java:61)
at com.snapterm.core.models.transaction.TransactionsDb.(TransactionsDb.java:49)
at com.snapterm.core.models.transaction.TransactionsDb.getInstance(TransactionsDb.java:41)
at com.snapterm.core.SnapTerm.onCreate(SnapTerm.java:42)
at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.setUpApplicationState(ParallelUniverse.java:164)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.setUpApplicationState(RobolectricTestRunner.java:430)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:177)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

I haven't had any luck fixing this error no matter how I go about manually trying to load this lib. I believe it's a current limitation with Robolectric finding native libs but am curious if anyone has tried these two together and made them successfully work.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: @drspaceboo A solution to this issue was posted and it's working for me.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. We have moved away from Robolectric. We want to be able to test Couchbase itself not abstract it away so we don't use it in our tests.

Comment: @drspaceboo I thought about that too but after looking into Couchbase, I realized that they do their own testing on their code.  So by abstracting it I'm still able to test the behavior of my code and maintain the efficiency from Robolectric.  It's not exactly an ideal solution but it works for now and I'm hoping it won't be an issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never been able to implement Robolectric test coverage around Couchbase, however you can use Couchbase and Robolectric in the same project provided you are using dependency injection using something such as Dagger.  What you need to do is define interfaces around all of the elements of Couchbase that you use and in any of your application code when you need to use those aspects of Couchbase you use the interface instead.  Then in order to get Robolectric to work you implement test versions of the interfaces in your test module.

The last step is you use Dagger to inject the actual Couchbase classes into your main App Module, and you inject the test versions in your test App Module.  This will allow you to write tests around your code by mocking your database layer.

Comment: I gave this a try and had to write wrapper classes around all of the Couchbase objects that I used.  After changing my code to use those wrappers, Robolectric was able to run.  I am using Dagger to inject my datasource and so far my tests are running, so thank you for the suggestion!